# Is this sentence, which mixes present and future tense, grammatically correct? ("Until the call to war resounds/when they shall face their bane")

Tags: grammar, past-tense, present-tense

Is the grammar in the third stanza valid or faulty? The preceding two stanzas are included only for context.

> His hall has held the highest host
> the dead in battle slain
>
> Who dwell within to feast and fight
> and train in jolly pain
>
> Until the call to war resounds
> when they shall face their bane

Does it need to be rewritten in a manner like this?

> Until the call to war will sound
> when they shall face their bane

Comment: It looks like a modern writer using "epic / heroic medieval" style (trashy doggerel, though, tbh! :). A couple of centuries ago it was normal to use ***shall*** rather than ***will*** in such contexts. But your version with ***shall sound*** is even "weirder" than the original! The modern version would be like *Go to sleep **until the alarm goes off**,  when you **will have** ten minutes to shit, shower, and shave before breakfast.*

Comment: What is this from? Is it something you wrote yourself? If not, please cite the source. (And as mentioned note that there has historically been a lot of variation in shall vs will, and continues to be some between countries and dialects.)

Comment: I'm not asking about shall vs will. We can consider those synonyms in this case. I'm asking about:

"Until the call to war **resounds**
When they **shall** face their bane"

The first line uses present tense. The second line uses future tense.
Is that a grammatical problem?

Comment: Until you understand this question, I shall/will keep on trying to explain it. [another example] The sentence has two different clauses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no tense problem there. Your suggestion with **will** would be ungrammatical:

> ... until the call to war will resound.

**until** wants a happening (present tense) not a projected event (with auxiliary **will** conveying the future sense):

> Leave it in the oven until the bell **will ring**. <sup>ungrammatical</sup>
>
> Leave it in the oven until the bell **rings**. <sup>grammatical</sup>

With another subsequent clause:

> The cake-tray is left in the oven until the bell rings, whereupon you will turn the oven off and move the tray from the oven to the cooling rack.